# solution of the ODE $u du =ydx+xdy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, partial-derivative

In this case $u=u(x,y)$. When I saw this I just went on to taking iindefinite integral both sides yielding $ u^2=4xy+K $. Yet, the book I am using now got $udu=d(xy)$, which yields $ u^2=2xy+K$. I'm I right or the book is?

These are the details of what I did.
 $ \displaystyle \int udu = \int ydx +xdy $ which implies that $ \displaystyle \frac{u^2}{2}= xy +xy + K$

However, this is what I think they did to get the RHS.

RHS= $ \langle y, x \rangle \cdot d \langle x, y \rangle = \nabla (xy) \cdot d (\overrightarrow { r}) =d(xy)$.

However, I think my reasoning is okay? Help please.

Comment: Is it line integral? $ d(u^2)  = d (Area) ? $ an application of Green's theorem?

Comment: I know line integrals but I just can't relate this to problems of line integrals @Narasimham

Comment: "I just went on to taking improper integral both sides yielding..." Unless you show in details what you did there, it is difficult to say where you went wrong.

Comment: @Did I have added the details of what I did. I have also included what I think the guys in the book did.

Answer (score 1):

The screen copy below shows where is the mistake :

[image]